# RoC travel authorisation certificate

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, paperwork, taiwan

I am an Indian citizen wanting to travel to Taiwan later this year. I have an expired and used Schengen D visa. The visa was used by me 4 years ago. Am I eligible for the ROC certificate?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Taiwanese Bureau of Consular Affairs](http://www.boca.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=6464&ctNode=868&mp=2):

> 1.The applicant possesses at least one of the following documents issued by Australia, Canada, Japan, Korea, New Zealand, **any of the Schengen countries**, the United Kingdom, or the United States:
>
> O Valid resident or permanent resident card or Status
>
> O Valid entry visa (electronic visa must be printed out)
>
> O Resident card or **visa that has expired less than 10 years** prior to the date of arrival in Taiwan

**So yes, you can apply for the authorisation certificate.**

Comment: Although they do possess a Schengen visa, it's expired. I would think that is is now not a valid visa - you couldn't actually use it to enter the Schengen area. From the quote shown, that would imply that they can't apply for the certificate I'd think.

Comment: @simonatrcl Jesus, I bolden the text and still people don't notice. Again, "**visa that has expired less than 10 years prior to the date of arrival in Taiwan**".